# Avoiding the company of persons who are not spiritually advanced

Tags: bhagavata-purana, spirituality, kapila

According to SB 3.29.18:

> TEXT 18
>   ādhyātmikānuśravaṇān
>   nāma-saṅkīrtanāc ca me
>   ārjavenārya-saṅgena
>   nirahaṅkriyayā tathā
>
> TRANSLATION
>   A devotee should always try to hear about spiritual matters and should always utilize his time in chanting the holy name of the Lord. His behavior should always be straightforward and simple, and although he is not envious but friendly to everyone, he should avoid the company of persons who are not spiritually advanced.

Hi, in the passage, writen by Lord Kapila, does he explictly say to avoid people who are not spiritually advanced? Because according to the english translation it says he does. If so, how do we define someone who is spiritually advanced? Also isn't being non- judgemental part of being in the spiritual path? In other words shouldn't we not avoid someone simply because he is not spiritual? He could still be a good person, and be kind and compassionate but not necessarily spiritual?
Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: One who constantly strive for the highest truth is a spiritual person. And you don't need to avoid compassionate & kind dudes or divas, just don't get influenced from them. If you can negatively get influenced, better avoid them. Only scriptures are right source of knowledge.

Comment: Ok thank you for answering my question. Just would like to clarify though, Did lord kapila explicitly say to avoid people who are not spiritually advanced, or that instead we should rather keep the company of saints?

Comment: There is not a single word in the verse given by you, which corresponds to "not spiritually advanced". Who has translated this? It is complete wrong translation as well as very misleading.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for clarifying this. I found this translation online. If possible could you kindly shed light as to what the actual translation is? Thank you